# Excel cell formatting based on content of adjacent cells

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a VBA code to format a given Excel cell based on the content of adjacent cells.

For instance, I would like to colour in yellow cell C3 **IF** cell B3 contains the letter "R" **AND** cell D3 contains the letter "M". I would like to apply this logic to an entire area of my worksheet.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Giacomo

Comment: If you record a macro to mimic this then you might be able to obtain a start position for further coding. SO is not a coding service

Comment: Thanks Miguel for your comment. I indeed tried this way; however, Excel does not understand the reason why (i.e. the specific content of the adjacent cell) I highlight the cell under scrutiny. I believe this step is the major issue here.

Comment: @GiacomoCapelli Do you mean VBA or do you mean a formula that you apply via conditional formatting?

Comment: B and D are not adjacent. "I would like to apply this logic to an entire area of my worksheet." - I am uncertain what this means? You are comparing B & D and colouring C yellow: How does this work for the entire unspecified area?

Comment: I don't think VBA is needed at all for this if you are simply comparing two columns. Use conditional formatting with an AND formula as this will use in built optimized functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very very basic code layout. This colours the text red. You can find out how to colour in yellow!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub do_it()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range(Range("a1"), Range("d" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If c.Column = 2 And c.Value = "R" And c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "M" Then
       c.Offset(0, -1).Select
       With c.Font
           .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This does for the columns mentioned though i think the OP should clarify their question.